# How to fix a mismatch in array shape between layers

Tags: arrays, keras, deep-learning

I'm building a reinforcement DNN (DQN) but got the following error as my data was sent to the model:
**ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (64, 4, 1)**

I'm using this a input of (1,139) with a minibatch size of 64, making it: (64,1,139).

```
def create_model(self):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(1,139), return_sequences=True, stateful=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())  

    model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, stateful=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

    #Model compile settings:
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I ran a summary on the model:

```
 Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 128)            137216    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 1, 128)            512       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 128)            131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 1, 128)            512       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1, 32)             4128      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 132       
=================================================================
Total params: 274,084
Trainable params: 273,572
Non-trainable params: 512
_________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 128)            137216    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 1, 128)            512       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 128)            131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 1, 128)            512       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1, 32)             4128      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 132       
=================================================================
Total params: 274,084
Trainable params: 273,572
Non-trainable params: 512
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Shouldn't the flatten layer make it a 2D array? Any ideas? :-/

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any sense have this line

`model.add(Flatten())`

After a Dense layer. I believe you were supposed to put it after your second LSTM, right?